# ssh over the internet into a server and access a local machine in that network

Tags: server, ssh

So I have set up ssh and everything is working fine, I only want to see what is possible. The set up that I have is one Ubuntu server and a few laptops and  a desktop PC. On my server there are things installed like mail and web.

Lets say that I'm in my parents home and I want to ssh into my server than i just have to do ssh mydomain and I will get into my server. I'm looking for a possibility were I can login over the internet and access one of my local machines. So a command should look something like this:

ssh mydomain/local-ip-laptop1.

I did some tries but noting is working. Does somebody know of what I want is even possebol? And if it is possibly how does a command like that look like?

Comment: To keep it simple, one you have sshed into the server, you can just ssh into another machine on the lan. If you want to get fancy, look up ssh tunnels like these https://askubuntu.com/a/980896/243321

Comment: Tks that is realy helpful, i tried it and it is indeed working, but things are bound to get messed up quick. Is there also a way to do it in like one command. I will look into ssh tunnels i Think that you already set me on the right track

Comment: This seems like a basic networking question that has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You have two choices: Port forwarding on your router (port 2221 to machine A, port 2222 to machine B, port 2223 to machine C), or VPN Server (which assigns your remote machine a LAN IP address and tunnel so you can see all the other machines directly). Many consumer routers have both features built-in. Check your router settings to see what it can do for you.