# Grey background of VNC in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vnc, tightvncserver

I see some discussions about grey screen when connecting to a GNOME desktop via VNCVIEWER. For example, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800302/vncserver-grey-screen-ubuntu-16-04-lts).

The solution there is not fully compatible with 18.04 as neither the desktop is shown nor the taskbar.

See the picture

[image]

What can I do then?